# SQL error in database connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting an SQL error while establishing database connection in Java (Jdbc:Odbc). How do I fix this error?

Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class db {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:data","system","password");
            System.out.println("\n connection established");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from stud");
            System.out.println("details of empdata\n");
            while(rs.next())     {
                 System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch(Exception e)     {
            System.out.println("sql error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the error message and stack trace (if available).

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` to display the reason for the error. Showing `sql error` at exception and asking us what's wrong is ridiculous.

Comment: Possibly related (but impossible to tell without more information): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: Capitalize class names.

Answer (score -1):

/* Execute query requires string as argument and u have not use semi colon at query if u are getting class not found exception than handle it first
THIS SHOULD BE PASS IN DOUBLE QOUTES="select * from stud;"*/

```
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:data","system","password");
        System.out.println("\n connection established");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from stud;");//----HERE--*/
        System.out.println("details of empdata\n");
        while(rs.next())     {
             System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3));
        }
    } catch(Exception e)     {
        System.out.println("sql error");
    }
}
```

}